# Increasing text size adds extra padding to text in android

Tags: android, textview

I am facing a simple problem. I am increasing `textSize` in xml. As I increase `textSize` there is some extra padding coming all around the text. I don't want that.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/number"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="70sp"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
android:text="1"/>
```

How to remove that space inside the box?

Comment: Plese put your code here

Comment: Not recommended. But you can add padding to the negative number. This happens due to extra space in font characters.

Comment: check my answer it will help you a little by excluding the font paddings

Comment: If you eliminate that space some characters with accents, letters like the g etc, can be cut. If plan that all kinds of characters in different languages be well displayed that space must exist

Comment: that is actually expected behavior since the font contains paddings as well

Comment: i m facing same issue, did you find workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

try this it works quite fine in xml

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rizwan"
    android:padding="@null"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    />
```

if you want it in java it will be like this

```
youtextView.setIncludeFontPadding (false)
```

NOTE!: you can use negative padding or in points but its not recommended as this is the builtin boxModel padding of android

**IF THAT DOES NOT WORK THEN as its stated in [OFFICIAL DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding) Each Font comes with own white spacing around**

try using a custom font in the asset folder instead of default ROBOTO like its done in this awesome project [here](https://github.com/SunilKushwah/Code-Discussion)

Credit goes to @Sunilkushwah.  he uses "HVD Fonts - BrandonText-Light.otf" and it do solves the problem

Comment: Please see my updated question. Your answer not working for me.